# run php script in the background

Tags: command-line, scripts, php, php-cli

I tried the following command line code to run a php-script in the background.

```
php server.php &
```

This works. The problem is: if I close the terminal window on my computer, the php-script also stops. I want it to run "infinite". It's a websocket server so it has to be running constantly.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found the answer already (asked this question way to early I guess).

```
nohup php server.php &
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `screen` to open a virtual terminal, where the script can run.

I recommend to use `screen -S php_script`. Then you can run your script (even without &). With CTRL + A, D you can disconnect from the termial. You can reconnect with `screen -r` back to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

While Boba Fit's answer will help you, I think there is a better way of running your server in the background. In case of a reboot, you likely want to have your server running again.

I used [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) in a similar use case. I my case it was a long running PHP process to schedule background tasks by using [JMSJobQueueBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation).

The only thing you have to setup is supervisor and configure your process:

```
[program:your_websocket_server]
command=php server.php &
process_name=%(program_name)s
numprocs=1
directory=/tmp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=5
startretries=10
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=%capistrano.shared_dir%/jms_job_queue_runner.out.log
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile=%capistrano.shared_dir%/jms_job_queue_runner.error.log
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB
```